# is Test-net in Mist a private chian ? or public?

Tags: testnets

just run some contract on MIST , and link to Test-net. 
but cannot find my account's any transaction on https://testnet.etherscan.io/

why ? so Test-net is only local testing chain ?
MAIN ACCOUNT(0x5BA6F88841CDe3dF0522de852d7292938Cc1854F) done many transactions~ still cannot find record... 
[image]
tanks
HIPPO

Answer (score 0):

It's by default the Ropsten testnet: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

You can get some ethers to start with from this faucet: http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Comment: hello, just post my mist graphic, still cannot find any record on [ropsten]...

Comment: There is possibility that those transactions have not sent to the testnet and thus not mined by the network. You can check again the status of each transactions, especially the confirmation info.

Comment: OK i will try it , thanks everyone...^^"

Comment: Actually, if you select solo network, then that is a private blockchain. I can see that your balance is 33,618 ETH. That would take a very long time to mine on the Ropsten network.